# How to re-arrange Excel database from 1 long row, into 3 short rows and automatically repeat the process?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I would appreciate help on the above-mentioned topic.
I am unfamiliar with Visual Basic for Excel, so will need step-by-step guidance (if solution is via Visual Basic).

For example :-
Row 1, Sheet A:

```
A1  B1  C1   D1  E1  F1  G1  H1   I1
```

To be re-arranged into Sheet B :

```
Row 1 :  A1,  B1,  C1
Row 2 :  D1,  E1,  F1
Row 3 :  G1,  H1,  I1
```

The Sheet A (database sheet) has a lot of rows (example 3,000 rows), hence the Sheet B is estimated to have 9,000 rows (i.e. 3 x 3,000).

Thanking you in anticipation of your speedy response.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this lies in using the excel Row/Column and [Indirect sheet function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010342609.aspx).

if the original data is in sheet1, then in sheet 2 paste the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"R"&CEILING(ROW(Sheet1!A1)/3,1)&"C"&MOD(3*(ROW(Sheet1!A1)-1)+ COLUMN(Sheet1!A1)-1,9)+1,FALSE)
```

and then drag the formula across and down

Comment: Dear Jason Lewis.  I have tried your suggestion and it worked beautifully!  Thank you very much for your assistance and quick reply.  Your formulae seems complex with multiple functions such as 'indirect', 'ceiling', 'mod',  'false',  which I'm unfamiliar with, and I'm trying to digest them now.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I was kind of in a hurry when I wrote it and didn't have time to explain it. but here is what I suggest you do, on a separate sheet, try parts of the equation like make cell A1=Row(Sheet1!A1)     that one just returns the row number as it happens. The point is though, just to try the different bits out until you understand each bit

Comment: the "False" is not a command but an option to the Indirect function, which tells it to use the R1C1 cell referencing rather than A1 style

Comment: As I still have problems comprehending, I posted another 'almost similar' question at  http://superuser.com/questions/763867/how-to-re-arrange-excel-database-from-1-long-row-into-3-short-rows-of-unequal-l  .    Hoping you have patience to engage my follow up question!