# How to re-arrange Excel database from 1 long row, into 3 short rows of unequal lengths and automatically repeat the process?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

This question is an extension/continuation of my previous question at [How to re-arrange Excel database from 1 long row, into 3 short rows and automatically repeat the process?](https://superuser.com/questions/759141/how-to-re-arrange-excel-database-from-1-long-row-into-3-short-rows-and-automati)  which was answered by Jason Lewis of which I'm grateful.   But being a dummy in "Indirect' Excel function, I need assistance again :

For example :- In Sheet A, Row 1 has the following data in each cell (all together 72 cells occupied):

> A1  B1  C1   D1  E1  F1  G1  H1   I1  J1  K1  L1  M1  N1  O1  P1  Q1 
>   R1  S1  T1  U1  V1  W1  X1  Y1  Z1  AA1  AB1  AC1  AD1  AE1  AF1  AG1 
>   AH1  AI1  AJ1  AK1  AL1  AM1  AN1  AO1  AP1  AQ1  AR1  AS1  AT1  AU1 
>   AV1  AW1  AX1  AY1  AZ1  BA1  BB1  BC1  BD1  BE1  BF1  BG1  BH1  BI1 
>   BJ1  BK1  BL1  BM1  BN1  BO1  BP1  BQ1  BR1  BS1  BT1

To be re-arranged into Sheet B in the following format:

> Row 1 :  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  I1  J1  K1  L1  M1  N1  O1 
>   P1  Q1  R1  S1  T1  U1  V1  W1  X1  Y1         Z1  AA1  AB1  AC1  AD1 
>   AE1  AF1  AG1  AH1  AI1
>
> Row 2 :  AJ1  AK1  AL1  AM1  AN1  AO1  AP1  AQ1  AR1  AS1  AT1  AU1 
>   AV1  AW1  AX1  AY1  AZ1  BA1  BB1  BC1  BD1  BE1  BF1  BG1  BH1  BI1 
>   BJ1  BK1
>
> Row 3 :  BL1  BM1  BN1  BO1  BP1  BQ1  BR1  BS1  BT1

The Sheet A (database sheet) has a lot of rows (example 3,000 rows, each rows has 72 cells occupied with data), hence the Sheet B (reformatted database) is estimated to have 9,000 rows (i.e. 3 x 3,000) of unequal lengths.

Thanking you in anticipation of your speedy response.

Comment: Can you also clarify what "start a new row". Is it X number of characters (doubtful because you've stated each row has unequal lengths). Why did ROW2 start with AJ1?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear. I can see that Sheet 1, A1 has 72 cells. What I can't understand is how you want to split this into 3 rows. Sheet B A1 is A1 - AI1. Why AI1? Why not B1 or BK1? Why does Sheet B B1 start at AJ1 and end of BK1? Why doesn't it end on BT1 or BD1? Hopefully this makes my question easier to understand?

Comment: Sheet A, Row 1 has 72 cells with data (example of data as per A1 to BT1).   Those 72 cells in Sheet A to be re-arranged into Sheet B into the followings :  Sheet B Row 1, 35 data (example of data, from A1 to AI1),  Sheet B Row 2, 28 data (example of data, from AJ1 to BK1) and lastly Sheet B Row 3, 9 data (example of data, from BL1 to BT1).  Therefore, Sheet B has 3 Rows of data of 'unequal lengths'.   I'm not sure whether Excel can do it or need to delve into Microsoft Visual Basic for Excel to do it, hence Excel and VBA are being tagged to this question.

Comment: I would appreciate some help if this could be done.  I'm downloading data from an accounting package (Accounting Package A) using Seagate Crystal Reports (CR) and the output from CR is typically arranged into long rows (download format).   As I need to upload data downloaded (from Accounting Package A) into a different accounting package (Accounting Package B), I am required to re-arrange the database from 1 long row into 3 shorter rows (in this case, 3 short rows of 'unequal lengths' (which is the uploading format), after which, then only it can be uploaded into Accounting Package B.

Comment: I'm a dummy in VBA (I'm worse in VBA compared to Microsoft Excel), so, I may need help on even how to activate VBA, input commands into VBA, and run VBA.  Sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: Do your own research, we're not here to do your job for you because you don't know how to do it!?

Answer (score 0):

This macro will do it

```
Sub AnotherGo()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Dim row2 As Integer
row2 = 1

Do While (True)

If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row) = "") Then
Exit Do
End If

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row2 & ":AI" & row2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row & ":AI" & row).Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row2 + 1 & ":AB" & row2 + 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AJ" & row & ":BK" & row).Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row2 + 2 & ":I" & row2 + 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BL" & row & ":BT" & row).Value

row = row + 1
row2 = row2 + 3

Loop

End Sub
```

I have 3 rows in Sheet1

[image]

And Sheet 2 looks like (After macro runs)

[image]